# Storing API keys and passwords in web2py

Tags: web2py

I am creating a web2py application which will pull a bunch of data from different sources. What's the best way to store the API keys and passwords? Appconfig.ini seems to me as a bad option here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Python keyring lib** to more safely store and retrieve an API key into the underlying Operating System's Keyring service. As an optional optimization, you can then store the key in Web2py's *cache.ram* to avoid having to retrieve API key from the OS for every request.

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring

Answer (score 2):

Thanks so much Himel Das for the initial answer !

In my lib [`odsclient`](https://smarie.github.io/python-odsclient/) I ended up implementing a series of alternatives, from the most secure (keyring as you suggested) to the less ones (OS environment variable, git-ignored text file, arg-passed apikey possibly obfusctated with `getpass()`).

You might wish to have a look for inspiration, see [this part of the doc](https://smarie.github.io/python-odsclient/#c-declaring-an-api-key) in particular.